# Why am I getting base class undefined?

Tags: c++, include, undefined, subclass, base-class

**Hello StackOverflow!**

I'm trying to make some kind of algebraic solving code. I've laid out some basic structure. But I stumble uppon the error that a subclass finds the base-class being undefined. I've tried removing `#pragma once` and removing and changing include statements here and there. But I cannot figure it out.

I think it has something to do with the files including eachother, but from what I thought I knew from before. That is supposed to be possible thanks to `#pragma once` and `#ifndef`. Please advice me on what I am doing wrong here!

*Expression.h:*

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MATH_EXPRESSION_H
#define MATH_EXPRESSION_H

#include <string>

#include "Variable.h"
#include "Value.h"

class Expression {

public:
    virtual             Expression*     eval(const Variable* var, Value* val)           = 0;
    virtual operator    std::string()                                           const   = 0;

    template<class T>
    bool                isType() {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
    }

};

#endif
```

*Variable.h:*

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MATH_VARIABLE_H
#define MATH_VARIABLE_H

#include "Expression.h"

class Variable : public Expression {
};

#endif
```

*Value.h:*

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MATH_VALUE_H
#define MATH_VALUE_H

#include "Expression.h"

class Value : public Expression {

public:
    float value;

    Value(float value) : value(value) {}

public:
    Expression* eval() { return this; }
    Expression* eval(const Variable* v, Value* val) {
        return this->eval();
    }

    operator std::string() const {
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
};

#endif
```

And this is the build error I am trying to solve:

```
Variable.h(7,36): error C2504: 'Expression': base class undefined
```

Comment: You have circular includes. That won't work. Remove `#include "Variable.h"` and `#include "Value.h"` from `Expression.h`, replace them with forward declarations.

Comment: Okay, but why isn't the result if I start by just including *Varaible.h:*

´#include "Expression.h"`
`#include <string>`

`/* #include "Variable.h" !!! Shouldn't proceed becuse we already included it*/`
`#include "Value.h"`

`class Expression { ... }`

`class Variable { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have circular references between your header files.

- If `Expression.h` is included in a translation unit before either `Variable.h` and `Value.h` are included, `Expression.h` will define the `MATH_EXPRESSION_H` guard and then include `Variable.h` before declaring the `Expression` class.  `Variable.h` will include `Expression.h` again, which is effectively a no-op because of the `MATH_EXPRESSION_H` guard.  So, the `Variable` class will be referring to an `Expression` type that hasn't been declared yet, hence a compiler error.
- If `Variable.h` is included in a translation unit before `Expression.h` is included, `Variable.h` will define the `MATH_VARIABLE_H` guard and then include `Expression.h` before declaring the `Variable` class.  `Expression.h` will include `Variable.h` again, which is effectively a no-op because of the `MATH_VARIABLE_H` guard.  `Expression.h` will then include `Value.h`, which will include `Expression.h` again, which is a no-op (see above).  So, the `Value` class will be referring to an `Expression` type that hasn't been declared yet, hence a compiler error.
- If `Value.h` is included in a translation unit before `Expression.h` is included, `Value.h` will define the `MATH_VALUE_H` guard and then include `Expression.h` before declaring the `Value` class.  `Expression.h` will include `Variable.h`, which will include `Expression.h` again, which is a no-op (see above). Then `Expression.h` will include `Value.h`, which is a no-op due to the `MATH_VALUE_H` guard.  So, the `Variable` class will be referring to an `Expression` type that hasn't been declared yet, hence a compiler error.

Let's look at this with actual code.

If `Expression.h` is included first, this is what the compiler will see after the preprocessor directives have been processed:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

class Variable : public Expression { // <-- error, Expression not defined!
};

class Value : public Expression { // <-- error, Expression not defined!
   ...
public:
    Expression* eval() { ... } // <-- error, Expression not defined!
    Expression* eval(const Variable* v, Value* val) { ... } // <-- error, Expression not defined!
    ...
};

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- OK!
};
```

If `Variable.h` is included first:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

class Value : public Expression { // <-- error, Expression not defined!
   ...
public:
    Expression* eval() { ... } // <-- error, Expression not defined!
    Expression* eval(const Variable* v, Value* val) { ... } // <-- error, Expression and Variable not defined!
    ...
};

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- error, Variable not defined!
    ...
};

class Variable : public Expression { // <-- OK!
};
```

If `Value.h` is included first:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

class Variable : public Expression { // <-- error, Expression not defined!
};

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- error, Value not defined!
    ...
};

class Value : public Expression { // <-- OK!
public:
    Expression* eval() { ... } // <-- OK!
    Expression* eval(const Variable* v, Value* val) { ... } // <-- OK!
    ...
};
```

So, this is a no-win situation regardless of which header is included first.

Since you are using only pointers to the various classes in function parameter types and return types, and not accessing any members of the classes, you can break this circular issue by replacing the `#include` statements in `Expression.h` with [**forward declarations**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) instead, eg:

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef MATH_EXPRESSION_H
#define MATH_EXPRESSION_H

#include <string>

// forward declarations
class Variable;
class Value;

class Expression {

public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0;
    virtual operator std::string() const = 0;

    template<class T>
    bool isType() {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
    }

};

#endif
```

The declaration of `Expression` only needs to know that `Variable` and `Value` exist, not what they look like inside.  Same with the declaration of `Value` only needing to know that `Variable` exists, not what it looks like inside.

So, let's look at what this change does to the code that the compiler sees after the preprocessor directives are processed.

If `Expression.h` is included first:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

// forward declarations
class Variable;
class Value;

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- OK!
    ...
};
```

If `Variable.h` is included first:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

// forward declarations
class Variable;
class Value;

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- OK!
};

class Variable : public Expression { // OK!
};
```

If `Value.h` is included first:

```cpp
// content from <string> ...

// forward declarations
class Variable;
class Value;

class Expression {
public:
    virtual Expression* eval(const Variable* var, Value* val) = 0; // <-- OK!
    ...
};

class Value : public Expression { // <-- OK!
    ...
public:
    Expression* eval() { ... } // <-- OK!
    Expression* eval(const Variable* v, Value* val) { ... } // <-- OK!
    ...
};
```

This does mean that you will have to `#include` the `Variable.h` and `Value.h` headers in any other source/header files that need to actually access the members of `Variable` and `Value`.

Whenever you are dealing with declarations that only use pointers/references to a type and not any members of that type, you should prefer a forward declaration for that type, not a header file include.  This will ease the burden of the compiler, and avoid any potential circular issues.